# Adding dns entry for subdomain in another subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

I have a now created a subdomain - **api.domain.com**.
Now I want to create **1.api.domain.com**, **2.api.domain.com**.
Each pointing to different servers.
Is that possible?

I want to make this happen in aws route 53.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. `1.api.example.com.` is a different name than `api.example.com.`, so all the three can have their own `A` records.

With AWS Route 53 you can have all of these in the same `example.com` zone. You'll just use `1.api` in the name field.

Comment: That worked, But now my SSL certificate is throwing error that its not for  api.example.com. I registered cert for example.com.

Comment: That's a totally different problem. You either need one certificate per hostname with the exactly matching CN, or a shared wildcard `*.example.com` certificate.

Comment: Great, Thanks. 
Is there any way to enable email too? for the domain 1.api.example.com and api.example.com?

I have setup email for example.com.

Comment: Do you actually need to receive emails on `something@1.api.example.com`? You can add `MX` records for the subdomains. They can point to self or somewhere else.